# Android/Java: why does my ConstraintLayout leak?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, memory-leaks, leakcanary

My app has a **memory leak**, according to *LeakCanary*.

It's the `ConstraintLayout` of `MyFragment`. I'm trying to fix it by nulling the `View` within `onDestroyView()`, without success.

Please note that I'm loading `MyNestedFragment` within a `MyFragment`.

**MyFragment.java**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    private View view;
    private FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private Map<String, Fragment> fragments = new HashMap<String, Fragment>();
    private Fragment fragment;
    private ConstraintLayout contentContainer;    

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myfragment_layout, container, false);

        fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.myfragment_tablelayout);
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(onTabSelectedListener);

        contentContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.myfragment_contentcontainer);

        if (getContext() != null) {
            showFragment(MyNestedFragment.class);
        }

        return view;
    }

    public void showFragment(Class fragmentClass) {
        try {
            if (fragments.containsKey(fragmentClass.toString())) {
                fragment = fragments.get(fragmentClass.toString());
            } else {
                fragment = (Fragment) Class.forName(fragmentClass.getName()).newInstance();
            }

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.myfragment_contentcontainer, fragment).commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        view                = null;
        fragmentManager     = null;
        fragments           = null;
        contentContainer    = null;
    }        
}
```

Any idea how to fix the memory leak?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**
ConstraintLayout dependency:
`implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'`

Comment: Try to update the dependency to 1.1.3, may be it will help

Comment: @warlock which dependency to you mean?

Comment: constraint layout:  
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

Comment: And if you want to show a nested fragment, use childFragmentManager instead of fragmentManager

Comment: @warlock Thank you for clarification. I'm already using `1.1.3`, but the `childFragmentManager` is new to me.

Comment: @warlock Please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. The leak was fixed by using the `childFragmentManager`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to show a nested fragment, use `childFragmentManager` instead of `fragmentManager`